# load viewController from class in swift

Tags: swift, controller, storyboard, viewcontroller

Hi i am start to develop in swift recently and i am little confuse.

I have login system that know if the user authenticate or not.

The model check if the user authenticate or not login -  by loginManager type NSObject.

after the loginManager verfiy if the user login it need to load the correct storyBoard.

I have viewController -> ProfileViewController, how I can load programaticly this ViewController from loginManager in real Time?

Hi try to call this funcation but I get black Screen, I dont know what do to

```
 override init() {

    var profileViewController = profileViewController()        

    let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)

    let vc:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("profileViewController") as profileViewController

    vc.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
    vc.viewWillAppear(true)
}
```

Comment: first check for the identifier u placed (i.e profileViewController).Maybe identifier contains Capital letters.

Comment: I checked and didn't found any chnages, do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: we need to see 2 things... the Story board  file to see how you have setup the segue method, since you are using Nav Controller hopefully you put it as a 'push'... However since you are saying you are getting a Black Screen I suggest you go to your ProfileViewController.xib file and add this to its name, the project name: myprojectNameExactlySpelled.ProfileViewController.xib